# how do you copy a particular cell from a sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmdPh2_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow1 As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mycode As String
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Set ws = Sheets("Phase 2")
    Set sh = Sheets("MA Form")
    mycode = sh.Cells(9, 3).Value
    With ws
    lastrow1 = ws.Range("c" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 3 To lastrow1
            If Worksheets("Phase 2").Cells(lastrow1, 3).Value = mycode Then
                Sheets("Phase 2").Range(lastrow1, 2).copy
                For m = 4 To 11
                    With sh
                        Range(9, m).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End With
                Next m
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range(lastrow1, 2)` and `Range(9, m)` are not valid range referencing. You probably meant to use `Cells`.

Comment: You would also want to precede Cells(9,m) with a period.  `.Cells(9,m)` to use the `With` statement.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Cell to Range

- This could put you on the right track. The constant copying to the ninth row looks kind of suspicious. Also, your mixing `Cells` and `Range` doesn't make it easier.
- At this stage, try to qualify each range, worksheet, and workbook e.g. `sws.Range(...)` or `sws.Cells(...)`, `wb.Worksheets(...)`, and `Set wb = ThisWorkbook`. When you fully understand this, then slowly start using the `With` statement.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdPh2_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim sLastRow As Integer
    Dim sRow As Long
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim mycode As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Phase 2")
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets("MA Form")
    mycode = dws.Cells(9, "C").Value
    
    sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
    For sRow = 3 To sLastRow
        If sws.Cells(sRow, "C").Value = mycode Then
            sws.Cells(sRow, "B").Copy dws.Cells(9, "D").Resize(, 8)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. Though I made some reconstruction at the last part of the code, the beginning flow helped me a lot. Hope I can come back again for some other points of query.